# How to create a list in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Javascript can read the list using for loop.
e.g

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static List<EmpName> GetData(int startIndex, int maximumRows, string sort, string filter)
    {
        var emp = objClient.GetData(startIndex, maximumRows, sort, filter);
        List<EmpName> lstEmp = new List<EmpName>();
        foreach (var item in emp)
        {
            EmpName objEmp = new EmpName();
            objEmp.ID = item.ID;
            objEmp.Name = item.Name;
            lstEmp.Add(objEmp);
        }
        return lstEmp;
    }

Javascript:
function ReadList(lstEmp)
{
     for(var i=0;i<lstEmp.length;i++)
     {
          alert(lstEmp[i].ID+" "+ lstEmp[i].Name);
     }
}
```

I want to create a list in javascript i.e List to perform various operation at client side how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to create a List in JS.

The easiest one being

```
var l = [];
l[0] = "a";
l[1] = 1;
```

another way todo so is

```
var l= [1,"as",func];
```

refer [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp)

Comment: Actually i was looking for this.                                     var lst = [];
                lst[0] = [10, 'ABC'];
                lst[1] = [40, 'DEF'];
                lst[2] = [70, 'GHI'];

                for (var k = 0; k <= lst.length - 1; k++) {
                    alert(lst[k][0] + " " + lst[k][1]);
                }    Thanks your code helped me find the soln